# Google Scholar user profile has disappeared from search results

Tags: google-scholar

I have a public user profile on Google Scholar, and my user profile used to show up when I searched my name on Google Scholar. However, as of about two weeks ago, it no longer appears in the search results, although it still appears if I click "My Citations." I double-checked that the profile is still public, and indeed, it even shows up on regular Google if I search my name.

How can I get my user profile to show up in the Google Scholar search results again?